# php not returning data to query ajax function

Tags: php, ajax, search, return

I have  and ajax function in my page to load data from the php that its posting to. The only problem is that the data doesn't get returned from the php page. Please take a look and tell me if I have any mistakes in the code. Any help very well appreciated. Also this all is supposed to be without refreshing.

```
$('#filterByPrice button', '#filterByPrice button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'filter-data.php' ,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('.container').html("");
            $('.container').html(data);
        }
    });


});
```

And the PHP file is:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['filter'])){

    $searchStr = $_SESSION['searchString'];
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];
    if(!is_array($filter)){
        require_once('Connections/conn.php');

        $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT * FROM happyhours
        WHERE (city LIKE :keyword OR zipcode LIKE :keyword)
        AND cost = '$filter'");
    }
    else {
        $filter = implode(', ', $_POST['filter']);
        require_once('Connections/conn.php');

        $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT * FROM happyhours
        WHERE (city LIKE :keyword OR zipcode LIKE :keyword)
        AND dayOfTheWeek LIKE '$filter'");
    }

            try{
                $stmt->execute(array(':keyword' => $searchStr.'%'));
                }
            catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo $ex->getMessage();
                }
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $each = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($count > 0){

        do {

        echo '<table id="results" width="700px" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="5" width="130" id="photo"><a class="lightbox" href="'.$each['imageURL'].'"><p>'.$each['name'].'</p><img id="hh-image" src="'.$each['imageURL'].'" width="80" height="80" /></a></td>

        <tr><td id="hh-name" style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:16px; font-family:\'Myriad Pro\'; font-weight:500" width="560" height="20"><'.$each['name'].'</td></tr>

         <tr><td> <a href="'.$each['googleMap'].'" target="new" style="font-size:14px">'.$each['address'].'</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:14px; font-family:\'Myriad Pro\'" height="20">'.$each['phone'].'</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:14px; font-family:\'Myriad Pro\'" height="20">'.$each['dayOfTheWeek'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;('.$each['hours'].')</td>
      </tr>
    </table>';
} while($each = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

}

}

 ?>
```

Comment: is your query returning any results? did you check?

Comment: yes is returning whats expected

Comment: FYI, you don't need `.html("")`. The second `.html()` completely replaces the HTML.

Comment: so if your query return any data, your php code WILL output and ajax will return that data. did you check if your php page is working properly with developer tools?

Comment: Do you really want a separate table for each row of data that the query returns? Usually each row of data becomes a row of data in one big table.

Comment: You can't use the same `:keyword` placeholder multiple times in a query.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I want a separate table for each result. and I still get the results on the php side using the placeholder

Comment: Is error reporting enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat the same `:keyword` placeholder multiple times in a query, you have to give them different names.

```
if(!is_array($filter)){
    require_once('Connections/conn.php');

    $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT * FROM happyhours
    WHERE (city LIKE :city OR zipcode LIKE :zip)
    AND cost = :filter");
}
else {
    $filter = implode(', ', $_POST['filter']);
    require_once('Connections/conn.php');

    $stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT * FROM happyhours
    WHERE (city LIKE :city OR zipcode LIKE :zip)
    AND dayOfTheWeek LIKE :filter");
}

try{
    $stmt->execute(array(':city' => $searchStr.'%',
                         ':zip' => $searchStr.'%',
                         ':filter' => $filter));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I still get results on the server side using the same placeholder. I believe the problem is returning the php to the ajax function